# Simple Affy Differential Expression

Tags: rna-seq, bioconductor, differential-expression, microarray, rna

I think I have a fairly easy-to-solve problem.

I have an expression table generated from an Affy set. It has one row of gene names (already symbols) and then 180 sample rows. 181 rows total.

So I made another excel file with one row with three different phenotypes I want to compare. That row has a label ("classes") and 180 names. 181 rows total.

In R, I can import each of these

```
dat <- read.csv("expression.csv")
dat <- data.matrix(dat)
pheno <- read.csv("pheno.csv")
pheno <- data.matrix(pheno)
```

I can then fit them

```
fit <- lmFit(dat,pheno)
```

And ask for an eBayes from limma

```
fit <- eBayes(fit)
```

Now, when I view the topTable,

```
table <- topTable(fit)
```

My first column has numbers (like "834","1142"), when I'd expect to have gene names there (like "ACTR", "CHRNA1").

What am I doing wrong? Or, rather, am I doing anything right?

Thanks!

Comment: What are your rownames of `pheno`? BTW are you sure that `pheno` has only the phenodata relevant for your differential expression analysis? Which is your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do the first few lines of your lmFit input variables look like (i.e. `dat` and `pheno`)? Are the rows numbered, or do they use the actual symbols?

By default, I don't think `read.csv` expects a file to have row numbers (even though `write.csv` puts them in by default). Try adding a `row.names` parameter to the expression matrix read call:

```
dat <- read.csv("expression.csv", row.names=1)
```